# Rails 4 - redirect_to, show error message and preserve parameters

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

I have a Rails app where `Users` can get invited to join `Teams`. I'm having an `Invitation` object to identify which team the `User` have been invited to. I get the correct invitation by using a token, when users sign up and a token is present and found I add the `User` to the `Team`. The URL looks like this:

```
[baseurl]/signup/invitation_token?invitation_token=[token]
```

However I'm having some trouble when users enter invalid or wrong information in the sign up form, like wrong confirmation password. When pressing submit in cases like this my app by default redirects the the index path.

```
[baseurl]/users
```

And the `@user.errors` is displayed.

This is when I use:

```
format.html { render action: :new }
```

In my create action in my `users controller`.

What I want is to still still be on the `signup path` or redirect back to the `signup path`, still have the same `invitation_token` parameter, and present the `@user.errors`. Optimally I would also like the values in the text fields to be preserved (less important).

I have tried to:

```
format.html { redirect_to signup_invitation_path(invitation_token: @invitation.token) }
```

This works for preserving my token, but my `errors` is not displayed and the text fields gets cleared.

So, I wonder. Is there an elegant and rails way to do what I want?

Comment: Could you include all the code for the signup (new?) action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option - and as a workaround - is to keep the errors temporary in the session like this `session[:signuperrors] = @user.errors` before you do the redirect. Then you would just check whether there are errors to display.

This works but without knowing more about the signup controller and the router I can't  provide a better solution.

Comment: I decided to instead send the error message using a flash message.

Answer (score 1):

I have built this exact flow before, so I have direct experience and advice.

1. Maintain a clear separation between signing up a user and accepting an invitation to join a team. Some people who receive invitations to join a team may already have user accounts and you (probably) don't want to require them to create another user account in order for them to accept a team invitation.
2. Use the Devise gem to manage user account creation. It provides features for creating user accounts, signing in, password recovery, etc. It's a bit complicated to understand in its entirety, but it's not so hard to get started with it. And rolling your own here is a massive waste of time.
3. With the two above in place, what you're trying to accomplish is pretty straight-forward. The link you email to someone to invite them to join a team becomes a link the `accept` action in your `InvitationsController`. This action should use Devise's `authenticate_user!` mechanism, which will do nothing if the user hitting the link is already signed in. Otherwise, it will put the user into a flow where they can log in to an already-existing account or create a new account. Either way, on successful login/signup, they will be automatically returned to your `InvitationsController` where you can now complete the action of accepting the invitation, i.e., assign the user to the team.

In this scheme, sign in/sign up are handled as the web version of a subroutine call -- it's a self-encapsulated process that, upon completion, "returns" to your intended action by executing a redirect. Doing anything else causes you to get these two systems needlessly entangled, as you've already seen -- the action of accepting an invitation has to become aware of user sign up errors, etc. It's just a mess. Keep 'em separated and you'll be much happier.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's not really what I was looking for. I've been using Devise before, I liked it, but I think authentication have become much easier in later releases of rails. I have got the flow you describe working, already signed up users don't have to sign up again to join teams etc. Team should be able to invite people that are not members yet. It wasn't the general flow I was looking for, bur rather how I can send the user errors by using redirect and perserve the url parameters. I'm pretty sure I would have the same issue by using Devise. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No, you wouldn't have the same issue if you used Devise as Devise handles this scenario in the way that I described. However, if you're intent on not using Devise, you can use the same mechanism that Devise uses: at the moment your user hits an endpoint that requires authentication and you find the user is not authenticated, save off the entire request url in the session. Then redirect to handle sign in/sign up, displaying errors using the standard Rails technique (render the form again with errors). On successful login/signup, redirect to the url you stored in the session (and then clear it).

Comment: Ok, interesteing. What I ended up doing for the moment is to send the error messages in a flash message. Moving to Devise would require quite a bit of work throughout the whole app. But it do have it's advantages, like your example above.

Comment: Putting the errors in the flash message works too -- it's just different from the way it's normally done in Rails. So you'll lose, for instance, the ability to highlight fields with errors in them or maintain the data that the user entered into the form when there's an error. If instead you put your destination url in your session, your form-handling mechanisms would be completely standard.